Ошибка api при работе в config.py
Файл config.py:
import pyrogram
#pip install pyrogram pyrotgfork tgcrypto
from config import (
    API_HASH,
    API_ID
)

def user2id(user):
    return app.getUsers(user).id
app = pyrogram.Client(
    api_hash=API_HASH,
    api_id=API_ID,
        name="bot"
)

@app.on_message()
def main(message, client):
    if message.giveaway:
        app.forward_messages(
            from_chat_id=message.chat.id,
            chat_id=user2id("@USERNAME"),
            message_ids=message.id
        )

app.run()

При запуске команды выводит:
Cannot fend reference 'APE_HASH' in 'config.py'
Cannot find referance 'API_ID' in 'config.py'


А что у вас в config.py написано?

это весь код который находится в config.py

Ну так вы подумаёте: у вас файл называется config.py вы пытаетесь что-то импортировать из другого config. Коннечно они у ничего не работает. Назовите файл config.py как-нибудь по-другому.

и постарайтесь не перепечатывать ошибку вручную.
